# Scrapy return nothing when crawling AWS blogs site

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Here's my attempt to crawl a list of URL in the first page of AWS blogs site.
But it return nothing. I think maybe there's something wrong with my xpath but not sure how to fix.

```
import scrapy


class AwsblogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'awsblog'
    allowed_domains = ['aws.amazon.com/blogs']
    start_urls = ['http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blogs = response.xpath('//li[@class="m-card"]')
        for blog in blogs:
            url = blog.xpath('.//div[@class="m-card-title"]/a/@href').extract()
            print(url)

Attempt 2
import scrapy


class AwsblogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'awsblog'
    allowed_domains = ['aws.amazon.com/blogs']
    start_urls = ['http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blogs = response.xpath('//div[@class="aws-directories-container"]')
        for blog in blogs:
            url = blog.xpath('//li[@class="m-card"]/div[@class="m-card-title"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            print(url)
```

Log output:

```
2019-11-06 10:38:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-11-06 10:38:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-11-06 10:38:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-11-06 10:38:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-11-06 10:38:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://aws.amazon.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://aws.amazon.com/robots.txt>
2019-11-06 10:38:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://aws.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-11-06 10:38:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/> from <GET http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/>
2019-11-06 10:38:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/> (referer: None)
2019-11-06 10:38:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong parser, The site is loading blog details via dynamic script function. Check out the page source for understanding the blog content availability.

For fetching the data, you should use dynamic data fetching techniques like below

```
1. Scrapy splash
2. Selenium
```